# Resize Highcharts chart in Angular UI Modal

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/NbZ1nCEnXXlOO7Ky0wSx) I have a Highcharts chart within an Angular UI Modal. The modal can be resized (implemented with jQuery UI resize).

The objective is to resize the chart to 100% width and height of the modal whenever the modal is resized. I defined 100% width and height in the Highcharts container but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div id="container" style="min-width:300px;width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </script>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
```

Javascript

```
    var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap']);
    app.controller("ctl", function($scope,$uibModal,$timeout) {

      var modalInstance;
      $scope.open = function () {
        modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
              animation: false,
              windowClass: 'the-modal',
              templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html'
            });

            $timeout(function(){

                $('.modal-content').resizable({
                      handles: "all"
                }); 

                plotChart();

            },10);

        };

        var plotChart = function(){

              $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
            }]
        });

        };

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the definition of the resizable plugin as follows by adding a listener to the resize event, for a more smooth end immediate effect set the `doAnimation = false`:

```
$('.modal-content').resizable({
    handles: "all",
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        $('#container').highcharts()
            .setSize(ui.size.width, ui.size.height, doAnimation = false);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have update the plunk with your solution [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VGFxec2IK7IhYPa771BI?p=info), the problem is that the chart needs to be resized as the modal is resized, not after you finish resizing.

Comment: I think it is a lag due to rendering, try setting `doAnimation = false'

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts listens for window resize, but not parent element resize. So a simple addition which fakes a window resize on end of a modal resize will kick highcharts into taking up available space...

```
$('.modal-content').resizable({
    handles: "all",
    stop: function(){
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
    }
});
```

If you're happy with the higher overhead and want to flicker the change during the resize then using `resize` and not `stop` as above will do that for you.